# Terraform - ensure value is set depending on if another value is also set

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'd like to enforce that a value is set rather than using the default "" if one of the other values is a certain string.

For example I have:

```
module "test_beanstalk" {
  tier = "Worker"
  queue = "myQueue"
///
}
```

in this, when `tier` is set to `worker` I'd like to enforce that `queue` is also set.  In the above example there's a scenario where the queue can be omitted resulting in aws spawning a generic one rather than using the queue that is required for that particular application.

Comment: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/25609, there are workarounds for that missing feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such feature is **not directly supported** in TF. But you can force TF to error out using `locals` and some condition that will simply lead to error if your verification fails. For example, in your `test_beanstalk` you can have:

```
variable "tier" {
  default = "Worker"
}

variable "queue" {
  default = ""
}

locals {
  if_queue_given = var.tier == "Worker" && var.queue == "" ? tonumber("queue can't be empty") : 1
}
```

The `tonumber("queue can't be empty")` will be executed and will lead to TF error, if the condition `var.tier == "Worker" && var.queue == ""` is `true`.

Comment: It helps if you prefix the string with `ERROR: `.